# Styling android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference

Tags: android, xamarin.android

First of all I am pretty new in programming Xamarin and Android. I have created a SeekbarPreference but some how they layout does not display all correctly. The value is dropping of from the box (see picture).

[image]

My styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">

  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#EC6A1E</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#EC6A1E</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/custom_toolbar</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material.Fix</item>
  </style>

  <style name="custom_toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="titleTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>

  <style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material.Fix"  parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="seekBarPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.SeekBarPreference.Fix</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Preference.SeekBarPreference.Fix">
  </style>
</resources>
```

Here is my settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference
          android:id="@+id/preference_range_seek_bar"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:key="range"
          android:title="Range"
          android:summary="Here you can set the range of your location"
          android:max="10000"
          android:defaultValue="500" />
    <android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference
          android:key="favRange"
          android:title="Favorite Range"
          android:summary="Here you can set the range of your Favorite location"
          android:max="10000"
          android:defaultValue="500" />
    <android.support.v7.preference.Preference android:title="Title" android:summary="This is the summary">
    </android.support.v7.preference.Preference>

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

What I do not understand is how can I find which xml attributes I can use on the SeekBarPreference to fix this. When I look in Googles Documents I cannot find a description of xml attributes on this SeekBarPreference.

I know my theme is fuzzy as I played a lot with it. But when I have it working I will adjust this.

Hopefully someone could help me, or have an example..

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. Here you go with the solution, testion on emulator running API 25:

Step 1, Create a new class that extends SeekBarPreference

```
public class CustomSeekBarPreference extends SeekBarPreference {
  private TextView mSeekBarValueTextView;

  public CustomSeekBarPreference(Context context,
      AttributeSet attributeSet,
      int i, int i1) {
    super(context, attributeSet, i, i1);
  }

  public CustomSeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int i) {
    super(context, attributeSet, i);
  }

  public CustomSeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
  }

  public CustomSeekBarPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder preferenceViewHolder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(preferenceViewHolder);
    mSeekBarValueTextView = (TextView) preferenceViewHolder.findViewById(android.support.v7.preference.R.id.seekbar_value);
    if (mSeekBarValueTextView != null) {
      LayoutParams layoutParams = mSeekBarValueTextView.getLayoutParams();
      layoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
      mSeekBarValueTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
  }
}
```

In your preferences.xml replace the SeekBarPreference class name with the custom class name.

```
<com.google.xxx.view.CustomSeekBarPreference
        android:key="cacheLimit"
        android:title="@string/setting_cache_limit_title"
        android:dependency="enableCaching"
        android:defaultValue="20"
        android:max="40"/>
```